# rewrite from c++ to Python

Tags: c++, python-3.x

Help me rewrite the code from c++ to Python
I just started learning Python and found a solution to the problem in c++, but I can't find it in Python, I just want to understand how it is solved, thank you in advance)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
  int n,i=1;
  cin>>n;
  while (i*i<=n)
  {
    cout<<i*i<<' ';
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please describe exactly what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: Did you try something in Python?

Comment: Which specific parts do you not know how to write in Python? The input? The output? The while loop? The multiplication?

Comment: Even if we did such requests (we don't), do you think receiving code would help you learn anything? Because I think it would be much, much more effective if you tried and wrote that in Python without looking for ready solutions.

Comment: How to port a program from one language to another: 1) Understand the observable behaviour of the program described by the code in the source language. 2) Implement the exact same observable behaviour in the new language adhering to the new language's best practices  and taking advantage of it's idioms. 3) Test both programs to ensure identical observable behaviour. Note that the code itself is not translated. Different languages have different rules and a literal translation of code has pretty much the same quality as literal translation of a spoken languages: You get gibberish.

Comment: Just as with spoken languages, some languages are close enough that a literal translation produces workable code. Python and C++ have about as much in common as English and Japanese and the results of a literal translation are [typically very bad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen To clarify, if it's clear what the program or snippet does, and the behavior is simple (i.e. it does one very specific thing), then the question is on-topic, and can be answered. Your point about the OP not learning as much as they could if they tried it themselves is true, but it doesn't make the question off-topic.

Comment: Side note: A question like this is often better received when accompanied by your best attempt. Maybe that attempt works or almost works and just needs a few tweaks to work well. Maybe it's a trainwreck, but at least a potential answerer has a baseline they can use as a foundation for the answer. Without the baseline the answer will have to look like the book of Genesis, "In the beginning, the User plugged in the computer..." to ensure nothing is missed. Plus don't underestimate the social importance of showing you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
program = """
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int n,i=1;
  std::cin>>n;
  while (i*i<=n)
  {
    std::cout<<i*i<<' ';
    i++;
  }
}
"""
f = open("a.cpp", "w")
f.write(program)
f.close()
os.system("g++ a.cpp -lstdc++")
os.system("./a.out")
```

Comment: Haha, this is brilliant. I want to both up-vote and down-vote it.